# How to delete all characters from a string which are in another string?

Tags: c, string, c-strings

I need to delete all letters from `s1` which are in `s2`.
I can't understand what is wrong with my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int i,j;
    i=j=0;

    for(i; s2[i]!='\0'; i++) {
        for (j; s1[j] != '\0'; j++) {
            if (s1[j] == s2[i]) {
                s1[j] = s1[j + 1];
                --j;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char w1[] = "abcde";
    char w2[] = "fghaj";
    squeeze(w1,w2);
    puts(w1);
    return 0;
}
```

but the output is:

```
abcde
```

What should I repair?

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code statement by statement in the debugger? What does it tell you?

Comment: iam a beginner, so it tells me nothing, moreover i have never use debugger before

Comment: Then take this as the perfect time to *learn* how to use the debugger. Being able to use a debugger is really mandatory if you want to do any kind of programming.

Comment: thanks, i will see it

Comment: Or before you even mess with a debugger try just adding printf statements inside your algorithm so you can get a paper trail showing how the algorithm progressed.  This is a more universal way to debug your program, since debugger interfaces vary.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the variable `j` is not reset to `0` in the inner loop for each iteration of the outer loop.

Secondly if a character has to be removed then all characters after it are not being moved to the left one position. You are simply replacing the removed character with the next character in the string.

The function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * squeeze( char s1[], const char s2[] )
{
    for ( char *p = s1, *q = s1; *q; ++p )
    {
        if ( !*p || !strchr( s2, *p ) )
        {
            if ( q != p )
            {
                *q = *p;
            }
            if ( *p ) ++q;
        }
    }
    
    return s1;
}

int main( void )
{
    char w1[] = "abcde";
    char w2[] = "fghaj";
    
    puts( squeeze( w1, w2 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
bcde
```

If you are not allowed to use standard string functions and pointers then the program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * squeeze( char s1[], const char s2[] )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0, j = 0; s1[j] != '\0'; ++i )
    {
        size_t k = 0;
        
        while ( s2[k] != '\0' && s2[k] != s1[i] ) ++k;
        
        if ( s2[k] == '\0' )
        {
            if ( j != i )
            {
                s1[j] = s1[i];
            }
            if ( s1[i] != '\0' ) ++j;
        }
    }
    
    return s1;
}

int main( void )
{
    char w1[] = "abcde";
    char w2[] = "fghaj";
    
    puts( squeeze( w1, w2 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown for the previous demonstrative program

```
bcde
```

Comment: thanks but i have to do it without pointers/indicators

Comment: @HGH What is the indicator?

Comment: i mean ' * " just dont know how to tell it in english maybe, pointer? index?

Answer (score 0):

Two problems in `squeeze`:

1. You need to reinitialize `j` to zero on every pass through the loop.
2. You need to copy the entire remained of the string one character to the left, not just the character following the one you want to remove.

I suggest you rewrite `squeeze` as:

```
void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int i,j;
    i=j=0;

    for( ; s2[i]!='\0'; i++) {
        for (j = 0; s1[j] != '\0'; j++) {
            if (s1[j] == s2[i]) {
              strcpy(s1+j, s1+j+1);
              --j;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: okay thanks, but how to do it without 'strcpt' ?

Comment: Write another loop to do what `strcpy` does.

Comment: i try:  void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int i,j,k;

    for( i= 0  ; s2[i]!='\0'; i++) {
        for (j = 0; s1[j] != '\0'; j++) {
            if (s1[j] == s2[i]) {
                for(k=j; k != '\0'; k++) {
                    s1[k] = s1[k+1];
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: @Bob Jarvis - Reinstate Monica The provided code with strcpy has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I see an issue here , your code is not entering this statement for some reason :

```
 if (s1[j] == s2[i]) {
            s1[j] = s1[j + 1];
            --j;
        }
```

your question might be why ? cause i and j are not set to 0 , try printing them and you will see that j will move to 4 but i is staying forever as 0
so as a start you can fix it by doing this

```
for(i=0; s2[i]!='\0'; i++) {
for (j=0; s1[j] != '\0'; j++) {
```

then you didn't copy the whole string and moved it back one step to rewrite over the found caracter , you only moved one caracter and left it blank
Exemple

```
input : abcde
output :b_cde
```

to fix this you have two methods :
use `strcpy` in order to move back one step the code

```
for(i=0; s2[i]!='\0'; i++) {
    for (j=0; s1[j] != '\0'; j++) {
        if (s1[j] == s2[i]){
            strcpy(s1+j, s1+j+1);
            --j;
        }


    }
```

or you can simply create the same function using a boucle for

```
for(i=0; s2[i]!='\0'; i++) {
    for (j=0; s1[j] != '\0'; j++) {
        if (s1[j] == s2[i]){
            for (k=j;s1[k] != '\0';k++)
            s1[k] = s1[k + 1];
            --j;
        }


    }
```

Comment: thanks, but how to do it without 'strcpy'? i know that i should use third loop, but i dont know how...

Comment: @HGH I'm not sure if you see the last part , try to refresh the page as i already wrote it of how to use the same function of strcpy using a for boucle

Comment: yeah, page didnt refresh, now i can see, thanks so much!

Comment: @HGH i'm glad that i managed to help you . Don't give up and try to use more exemples in order achieve your solution

Comment: @HGH it works in my side i have tried changing the string . Please provide more info in order to track the issue

Comment: @Saifeddine Ben Salem The provided code with strcpy has undefined behavior. But even the code without using the function is inefficient.

Comment: when i try: w1 = 'abab' and w2 = 'cb' the output is: 'aab', but it should be 'aa'

Comment: @HGH it printed `aa` for me

Comment: can u paste whole code? it was lot of changes and now iam confused where is correct

Comment: @HGH i never basiclly edited the code , the displayed version in the screen works

Answer (score 0):

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <string.h>

     int rem_str(char * porgstr, char * pdel) {
         if (!porgstr || !pdel) {
             return 0;
         }
         int i = 0;
         int j = 0;    
         char tmp[256] = {0};
         int len = strlen(pdel);
         for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            tmp[pdel[i]]++;
         }
         len = strlen(porgstr);
         for (i = 0, j=0; i < len; i++) {
            if(tmp[porgstr[i]] == 0) {
                porgstr[j] = porgstr[i];
                j++;
            }
         }
         porgstr[j] = 0;
         return 0;
     }
     int main () {
         char * input1 = strdup("origional string passed to program");
         char * input2 = strdup("sdel");

         printf("Input before del : %s\n", input1);
         rem_str(input1, input2);
         printf("String after del : %s\n", input1);

         return 0;
     }
```

Output:

```
      ./a.out 
     Input before del : origional string passed to program
     string after del : origiona tring pa to program
```